# DB query to delete configurable product images

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3

I am trying to delete the images of configurable products using DB query and delete the product images from the table **catalog_product_entity_media_gallery**, but images in the back office were not removed. any solution or reason for this behaviour?

Comment: get you DB backup and check below query,

Is it data okay?

Comment: Query 1: 
select * from  catalog_product_entity_media_gallery where value_id in (select value_id from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value where entity_id in (SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity` where type_id = 'configurable'));

Query 2:

select * from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity where entity_id in (SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity` where type_id = 'configurable');


Query3
select * from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value where entity_id in (SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity` where type_id = 'configurable');

Comment: if it seems okay replace "select * from" with "delete from"

Comment: @S.P getting this "ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'entity_id' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'"

Comment: which version of magento are you using?

Comment: Magento CLI 2.4.3-p1

Comment: Which query be wrong?

Comment: tried query 1  and got the above error

Comment: did you get record from SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_product_entity where type_id = 'configurable'

Comment: no, if I run the query it says the error